# Git: Automatically push new file

Tags: git, ubuntu, deployment

Is there a way to automatically commit new files and push them to git repository?

Here's my situation:
I have ubuntu web server, with git deployment – when I push from my local pc to "hub" repository, changes are automatically pushed to live/dev website. But the framework I use on the live creates some log files and I would really love to have them on my local repository.

Cool way would be some hook which would watch my repository and when new file is created, it triggers.

Is there a way to do this? Thanks y'all, -patrik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in way to do this with Git, since Git doesnt automate things by itself (though it offers interfaces for some automation by providing [hooks](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) -- those only work when you manually trigger a Git action first, though.

As a point of shameless self-promotion, I can tell you about [`gitwatch`](https://github.com/nevik/gitwatch) though, a script which uses [`inotifywait`](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools) to watch a specified file or folder, and commits all changes to it to the containing Git repo. It can also be configured to automatically push any new changes to a remote.

Please note that at this time there are a number of (not properly tested) new features in the `testing` branch. So if you want all the fancy stuff, use that ;)

The README isn't entirely up-to-date (mostly because of little demand so far), but if you understand a little bit of Bash scripting, you can just look at it directly (it also has a `-h` page which outlines its usage).

If you decide to try or use the script and have question about it, feel free to post an issue on its Github repo.

**Please note**: Since it uses `inotifywait`, it is only compatible with Linuxish operating systems. (`inotifywait` uses the `inotify` features of the Linux kernel.)